# How do i use rowcount in Function in sqlserver?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have faced a problem using rowcount in function in sql server 2000.
It shows an error like `Invalid use of 'UNKNOWN TOKEN' within a function.`

MY function is like this.

```
ALTER Function fnc_GetOpenShiftWorkID (@EMP_ID int,@Counter int,@date Datetime) returns int as
BEGIN

  SET ROWCOUNT @Counter
  declare @result int

  if exists(select * from tbl_org_workinghrs WHERE EMP_ID=@EMP_ID and SDATE=@DATE)  
  BEGIN

    select  @result= WORK_ID 
    from    tbl_org_working_hrs work_hrs
            inner join tbl_org_shift_group sgroup on sgroup.WH_ID=work_hrs.WORK_ID
            inner join tbl_org_workinghrs workhrs on workhrs.GROUP_ID=sgroup.GROUP_ID
    WHERE   EMP_ID=@EMP_ID 
            and SDATE=@DATE 
    order by 
            IN_START
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    if exists(select * from tbl_org_workinghrs where EMP_ID=0)
    BEGIN
      select  @result=WORK_ID 
      from    tbl_org_working_hrs 
      WHERE   IS_DEFAULTSHIFT=1
    END
  END

  return @result
END
```

Comment: Do you mean @@ROWCOUNT ?

Comment: Not related to your question but you should decide on using upper- or lowercase for reserved words. Either one is nice to read but mixing them gives a sloppy appearance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the function `SET ROWCOUNT @Counter`? What effect do you think/want it will have?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson:Actually i need the last rows value  in which row no. is not fixed.

Comment: In @result you are selecting the EMP_ID, then what is the use of @COunt?

Comment: Please tell me you don't have two tables in your schema with the names `tbl_org_working_hrs` and `tbl_org_workinghrs` (I.e. different only by an underscore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the value of the n'th row ordered by `IN_START`.

From SQL Server 2005 later you could use `top(n)` or `row_number()`.

In SQL Server 2000 you can use a table variable with an identity ID field as a temp storage.

Something like this.

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int identity, 
  WORK_ID int
)

insert into @T (WORK_ID)
select WORK_ID
from tbl_org_working_hrs work_hrs
  inner join tbl_org_shift_group sgroup 
    on sgroup.WH_ID=work_hrs.WORK_ID
  inner join tbl_org_workinghrs workhrs 
    on workhrs.GROUP_ID=sgroup.GROUP_ID
where EMP_ID=@EMP_ID and 
      SDATE=@DATE 
order by IN_START

select @result = WORK_ID
from @T
where ID = @Counter
```